# Solr * vs *:* query performance

Tags: solr, query-performance, edismax

We're running Solr 3.4 and have a relatively small index of 90,000 documents or so. These documents are split over several logical sources, and so each search will have an applied filter query for a particular source, e.g:

```
?q=<query>&fq=source:<source>
```

where `source` is a classic string field. We're using *edismax* and have a default search field *text*.

We are currently seeing `q=*` taking on average 20 times longer to run than `q=*:*`. The difference is quite noticeable, with `*:*` taking 100ms and `*` taking up to 3500ms. A search for a common word in the document set (matching nearly 50% of all documents) will return a result in less than 200ms.

Looking at the queries with debugQuery on, we can see that `*` is parsed to a `DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:*))`, while `*:*` is parsed to a `MatchAllDocsQuery(*:*)`. This makes sense, but I still don't feel like it accounts for a slowdown of this magnitude (a slowdown of 2000% over something that matches 50% of the documents).

What could be causing this? Is there anything we can tweak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are passing just `*` you are ordering to check every value in the field and match it against `*` and that is a lot to do. However when you are using `* : *` you are asking Solr to give you everything and skip any matching.

Solr/Lucene is optimized to do `* : *` fast and efficient!

Comment: How come * is so much slower than searching for any other common word though? `text:foo` is blazingly fast compared to `text:*`, no matter how many of the documents are matched by foo. Surely, searching for field:* should be able to forgo any actual matching on the contents of field, assuming it exists?

Comment: Because * is matching everything, and that is expensive. I don't know that much about Lucene, but I believe that searching for the terms is using more optimized data then when you are searching for * in every value of the field. Please read: http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Wildcard+Queries they mentioning performance of wild cards. At the moment I can't remember where I read, but somewhere in Solr Wiki there is mentioned against using field:* in favour of * : *

Comment: So it would appear that field:* is equivalent to running a regular expression match for * on any term found in the field. We are basically querying for what we know the Lucene index cannot provide us with a quick answer to, forcing it to do a cursory scan of the terms in the field.