# Solr Query Performance between with and without q=*:*

Tags: solr

Could anyone explain me if there are diff in performance between these 2 queries ?

```
q=field1:xxx
```

and

```
q=*:*&fq=field1:xxx
```

Also, it would be good if you know about documents for Solr performance turning and post them here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[fq](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) utilizes [filter cache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) which allows all the subsequent queries to be fetched from cache rather then the actual index.

Some helpful links :-
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/fq-vs-q-td495570.html
http://searchhub.org/2012/02/10/advanced-filter-caching-in-solr/
http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2011/11/solr-improving-performance-and-other-considerations/

Comment: Thanks. What about with and without \*:\* ? any different?

Comment: with and without is the same. If not query the default query is all documents.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800380/solr-vs-query-performance. So, only \* is totally different one?

Comment: as in the answer, * is searching in a specific default field e.g. text:* whereas *:* is a match all documents query.